# Get info between and after characters in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have these 2 strings:

```
/Iwish/I dont have this problem

I wish/I dont have this problem
```

How can I get /I wish/ and I wish/ ?

I tried something like:

```
select substring(column, charindex('/', column), charindex('/', column)) from my_table
```

I wanted to get also:

```
I dont have this problem
```

It´s possible to do this with?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
select substr(column, (len(column) - CHARINDEX('/', reverse(column)) +1) +1) 
from my_table
```